# Problems running scripts in ArcGIS 10.3 after upgrade from Python 2.6 to 2.7 as part of upgrading from ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, maps, arcgis, python-2.6

I'm new to python scripting, but have been trying to oversee a script that a former coworker created to help us automate mapmaking in my office.  We recently switched from ArcGIS 10.0 to 10.3, and from Python 2.6 to Python 2.7.  Now some of the scripts no longer work.  Does anyone have any tips to help get me started on likely reasons for this problem?  Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: The script that doesn't work does not produce an error.  It just gets to 100%, but is never completed.  It seems that 100% isn't actually 100% because it stops at the point of "Identifying optimal scale for tracts..." I've pasted in (below) the script starting at this point where the script just stops working.

```
##select by attributes, zoom to layer and copy scale
arcpy.AddMessage("Identifying optimal scale for tracts...")
mxd.activeView = "PAGE_LAYOUT"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(consCopy, "ZoomLayer")
addLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("ZoomLayer")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLyr)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(consCopy)
for row in urows:
    id = row.getValue("TRACT_UID")
    strID = str(id)
    expression = '"TRACT_UID" =' + "'" + strID + "'"
    selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ZoomLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    rScale = df.scale
    if rScale >= 48000:
        scale = 96000
    elif rScale >= 24000:
        scale = 48000
    elif rScale >= 22800:
        scale = 24000
    elif rScale >= 21600:
        scale = 22800
    elif rScale >= 20400:
        scale = 21600
    elif rScale >= 19200:
        scale = 20400
    elif rScale >= 18000:
        scale = 19200
    elif rScale >= 16800:
        scale = 18000
    elif rScale >= 15600:
        scale = 16800
    elif rScale >= 14400:
        scale = 15600
    elif rScale >= 13200:
        scale = 14400
    elif rScale >= 12000:
        scale = 13200
    elif rScale >= 10800:
        scale = 12000
    elif rScale >= 9600:
        scale = 10800
    elif rScale >= 8400:
        scale = 9600
    elif rScale >= 7200:
        scale = 8400
    elif rScale >= 6000:
        scale = 7200
    elif rScale >= 4800:
        scale = 6000
    elif rScale >= 3600:
        scale = 4800
    elif rScale >= 2400:
        scale = 3600
    elif rScale >= 1500:
        scale = 2400
    elif rScale >= 1200:
        scale = 1500
    elif rScale >= 600:
        scale = 1200
    else:
        scale = 600

    row.setValue("Scale", scale)
    urows.updateRow(row)
    row.setValue("rawScale", rScale)
    urows.updateRow(row)

del urows
del row

# add a scale for the topographic context maps
urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(consCopy)
for row in urows:
    case_id = row.getValue("Scale")
    value = case_id*2
    row.setValue("TopoScale", value)
    urows.updateRow(row)

#set new consplan as data driven pages index
arcpy.AddMessage("Setting new results as data driven pages index...")
for keepers in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if keepers.name == "Tract":
        keepers.replaceDataSource(workSpace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", consCopy)
    elif keepers.name == "Other tracts used by producer":
        keepers.replaceDataSource(workSpace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", consCopy)
    elif keepers.name == "TractIndex":
        keepers.replaceDataSource(workSpace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", consCopy)
del keepers     

# Turn off toolKit Layers
arcpy.AddMessage("Turning off ToolKit layers...")
offList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for off in offList:
    if off.name == "ZoomLayer":
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, off)
    elif off.name == "Practices (points)":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == consplanTitle:
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Land Unit Topology":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Active PLUs":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "AOI":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Base Layer":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Practices (lines)":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Practices (polygons)":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Legacy PLUs":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "Case PLUs":
        off.visible = False
    elif off.name == "History PLUs":
        off.visible = False



#clean up and clock out
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.dataDrivenPages.refresh()

del offList
del off
del mxd
del urows
del df
del id
del strID
del scale
del selection
del expression
```

Comment: You could start by providing a CMVE (i.e. the smallest possible script that worked with 2.6 that fails with 2.7 and more importantly what doesn't work, as in you either expected it to return a set of points and you got [] or an exception).  My guess would be ArcGIS API's changing more than python 2.6 vs 2.7 stuff.

Comment: Thank you, Foon.  I added more detail above.  Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, and as tedious and frustrating as I know from experience it is, one of the best ways to work through upgrade incompatibility like this is to include `AddMessage` after every single line of script. You know it's somewhere after your first line there, but before "Setting new results as data driven pages index..." (since you don't see that), and there is nothing obvious in the script that I can see which would break in 10.3. Unless they've eliminated `UpdateCursor` in favor of `da.UpdateCursor`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input everyone.  CWebster and I figured out that the **df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()** command was not selecting a feature to zoom upon (line 15 in the script above).  Because no feature was selected the script would not continue to run.

To fix this we replaced the **df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()** command line with **df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()** and the script now runs to completion again.

We are not sure if the issue was with the ArcGIS 10.3 update or with the Python 2.7 update, but if other people run into similar issues maybe this information can help.